# Implementing class extension in SwiftUI without wrapping UIKit class

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I have tried a number of GitHub repo's to add styling to my Apple's MapKit and each of their directions say to extend a class of ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate like the code below this. I understand a struct can not be extended like a UIKit class.

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {
            return MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tileOverlay)
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }

}
```

I have no problem implementing this in UIKit but I'm trying to further understand how SwiftUI would be integrated if I'm not wanting to wrap anything with a UIKit class.

Is it possible to workaround this extension while maintaining my SwiftUI does not wrap a UIKit class? I would like to understand how to implement this for future problems as many GitHub repo's follow instructions similar that extend some class but are not up to date to use with SwiftUI.

Further of my attempts I have a coordinator class I tried adding the function to my coordinator class that extended MKMapViewDelegate.

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

    let mapView = MKMapView()

    init(mapView: MKMapView) {
        super.init()
        mapView.delegate = self

        addCustomOverlay()


    }

    private func addCustomOverlay() {
        guard let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "overlay", withExtension: "json") else { return }

        do {
            let gmTileOverlay = try GoogleMapsTileOverlay(jsonURL: jsonURL)
            gmTileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
            mapView.addOverlay(gmTileOverlay)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Not surprisingly this managed to change the current location coordinator style but not the mapView tiles.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to workaround this extension while maintaining my
>   SwiftUI does not wrap a UIKit class?

You cannot do this w/o *wrapping a UIKit class*, because `MKMapView` itself **is a** `UIView`, so to use it in SwiftUI you MUST wrap it in `UIViewRepresentable`, which is explicitly provided by Apple for such cases.

Actually for me it is not clear a reason of such *self-limitation*... SwiftUI & UIKit are not enemies - they live together.

Comment: I am trying to work around the use of a extension for the delegate because you can't extend a struct. I am simply trying to use this class extension on a struct in a different way.